# Wallet Android/iOS with EXPO

Tags: react-native, expo, android-pay, wallet, apple-wallet

I'm looking for a lib that allows me to click: add wallet... to be automatically redirected to ios wallet or android wallet and add the ticket to the wallet. Is there any way to do this with expo?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?